# What's the Difference Between LT and T Directions?

Tags: metallurgy

What is the difference between LT and T directions in MMPDS (formerly MIL-Handbook 5)?

I hand understood that forming metal orients its grains, destroying the isotropic nature of 'pure metal' and that the "Long" direction is the length of the sheet/extrusion/etc, and that there were two transverse directions. There is the "Short Traverse" which would be the thickness (or "depth") of the sheet/extrusion/etc. There is also the "Long Traverse" direction which would be the width of the sheet/extrusion/etc.

But then MMPDS throws in a "T". Is this just for the times when you cannot distinguish between LT and ST (such as in a rod)? I also see datasets where specimen orientations are T *and* ST, which furthers my confusion. MMPDS itself doesn't seem to offer much further guidance.

Any explanations?

Answer (score 2):

I believe MMPDS is the new name for Mil-Handbook 5.  I have the 1998 version and it defines "T" as `***Applied torsional moment; transverse (grain direction); subscript “transverse”***.  Also see the figure below from Mil-Handbook 5.

In the figure, the "L", "T", and "S" planes are marked clearly.  Note that "T" and "L-T" indicate the same plane.

[image: MIL-Handbook 5 1998 definitions]

Answer (score 1):

For Fatigue and Fracture **the two letters are separated by a dash**. On the picture from Biswajit Banerjee imagine the loading of the part or test sample along the L direction, it gives the first letter L. The crack (or damage) can propagate now perpendicular to the load in S or T direction (laying L-T  and Standing L-S samples on the picture) giving the second letter. So L-T  means loaded in L direction with crack propagating in T direction.

On the other hand, the MMPDS-07 describes **Test Directions** as:

- L-Longitudinal: parallel to the direction of principal metal
  extension during manufacture of the product.
- LT-Long Transverse: perpendicular to direction of principal metal
  extension. In products whose grain structure clearly shows
  directionality (width-to-thickness ratio greater than two) it is that
  perpendicular direction parallel to the major grain dimension.
- ST—Short Transverse: perpendicular to direction of principal metal
  extension and parallel to minor dimension of grains in products with
  significant grain directionality. See also *ASTM G64-99*